# cd: bad substitution in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, glob, cd

Error

```
./sample.sh[245]: cd: bad substitution
```

This is line 455:

```
BSOld=`cd /opt/siebel/15.0.0.0.0/ses/siebsrvr/webmaster*;ls -lrt | grep *srf* | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'`
```

Comment: The line number reported in the error message isn't necessarily the line that actually causes a syntax error -- it's often a little before. Build a [mcve] that's tested to reproduce the bug when run *on its own* by someone who isn't you.

Comment: Also, you'll note that even your one line has a lot of feedback provided if you run it through http://shellcheck.net/ -- you should run your whole script through, and fix everything it finds.

Comment: (Not the cause of your specific error, but note that `grep *srf*` in general doesn't work at all; just `grep srf` to look for that substring -- but if you want to find the newest or oldest file matching a pattern, see [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) for best practices).

Comment: BTW, passing a wildcard to `cd` is generally bad form. What do you expect to happen if there's more than one directory that starts with `webmaster` in `siebsrvr`?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is `*`. Without `*` it works.

```
BSOld=`cd /opt/siebel/15.0.0.0.0/ses/siebsrvr/webmaster;ls -lrt | grep *srf* | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'`
```